# SSRS executing old sql

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report that I have updated the sql for one of the datasets. I have ran clean on the project and then rebuild. I deleted the original report from the server. I deployed the new report and then ran it. When I use SQL Profiler I can see that it executes the original SQL for the dataset. When I open the .rdl file in a text editor the SQL for the dataset has been saved correctly. What can be going wrong?

Comment: Some kind of caching, sounds like.

Comment: How are you running the new report, exactly?

Comment: Via a website. I've restarted the website to try and clear the cache.

Comment: I've also restarted the SSRS service to try and clear it's cache.

Comment: Is it being set by the expression?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. It was an 'I'm a beepin muppet' problem ;-) There were two very similar reports and I was changing the wrong one! Lesson to learn is remember to dig through the code to determine exactly which report is being invoked via your application before trying to update it!